# Does removing a user's community wiki post count toward their question ban?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, community-wiki, post-ban

I recently stumbled across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154119/invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tok/22911766#22911766) a few minutes ago on SO. It appears this question has been out there for some time and based on the comment string, may no longer contain reproducible code. It also appears based on a comment by [*Your Common Sense*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154119/invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tok/22911766#comment-34968642) that this post may have been flagged for deletion for some time now.

I've read up on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) meta SE post to learn about what purpose Community Wiki's serve. I understand that they are used to further the site's "evolving source of good information". Because of this voting does not reflect back on the answerer's account.

#### Question:

All this being said, does the deletion of a community wiki count toward a user's question/answer ban? It would appear that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154119/invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tok/22911766#answer-22911766) answer was added because the question had not been removed and the answerer no longer felt it was appropriate (or was possibly not willing to wait any longer for the close vote to propagate through the system queues). By making this a community wiki, it saves the answerer from receiving any negative reputation, when they blatantly violated the rules by posting a comment as an answer.

I guess what I want to know is, are there any repercussions for this behavior (i.e. another mark toward question/answer ban)? It just seems like this would be a dangerous precedent to set if no action were taken to discourage it.

Comment: And...it's gone.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Still not clear though, whether or not it counts against the ban?

Comment: [Similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225402/does-downvotes-flags-still-affect-the-original-owner-of-a-comunity-wiki-post-oth) on Meta SE. Note that it has remained unanswered for over a month and a half.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ok. Fair enough. I did not find that question earlier. My apologies. If no one objects to it, I'll leave this question open for some possible future feedback. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I think we have other people gaming the system in much more harmful ways, with much less benevolent intentions. Your Common Sense may have dodged a technicality in this one instance, but I think his motivation is worth considering, and how often this sort of thing actually happens. If we're going to "go after" any particular group of loophole-exploiters, this case is not where I would start.

Comment: @Chris I think that's completely valid. I agree 100%. I do believe there are probably much bigger fish to fry. Just seemed like a good idea to throw out as food for thought. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It's worth noting that YCS, for all intents and purposes, could never get answer banned.  He simply has way too many upvotes on answers.  Long, long before he could ever get answer banned he would have had to do more than enough to get manually banned by a moderator.  (Simply because he'd need to post tens of thousands of answers requiring deletion to end up banned at this point.)  Not that this question does have merit, because it can of course be relevant in other cases.

Comment: Its happend again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221931/convert-yuv-video-file-to-mp4-or-avi-format#26221931 It would be nice to know that users aren't *actually* getting away with this.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET And again here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949205/jquery-remove-event-handler-in-iframe/27949324#27949324...

Comment: @War10ck Unless something changed, there is no CW on that post.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ah, didn't notice that. My moderator flag was accepted and the post was rolled over to a non-community wiki post. Sorry about that. I didn't see that it had been accepted.